# Pandas, convert MultiIndex data frame some columns into rows

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a data frame with MultiIndex like this:

```
col_type1  col_type2   col_a           col_b           colc
col_type1  col_type2   col_x  col_y    col_x col_y    col_x  col_y
type11     type21      10     100      11    101      12     102
type12     type22      20     200      21    201      22     202
type13     type23      30     300      31    301      32     302
```

this is the create data frame code:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
{('col_type1', 'col_type1'): {0: 'type11', 1: 'type12', 2: 'type13'},
 ('col_type2', 'col_type2'): {0: 'type21', 1: 'type22', 2: 'type23'},
 ('col_a', 'col_x'): {0: '10', 1: '20', 2: '30'},
 ('col_a', 'col_y'): {0: '100', 1: '200', 2: '300'},
 ('col_b', 'col_x'): {0: '11', 1: '21', 2: '31'},
 ('col_b', 'col_y'): {0: '101', 1: '201', 2: '301'},
 ('col_c', 'col_x'): {0: '12', 1: '22', 2: '32'},
 ('col_c', 'col_y'): {0: '102', 1: '202', 2: '302'}})
```

I want to melt this data frame to this format, keep the `col_type1`, `col_type2` and convert the first level columns to rows:

```
col_type1 col_type2  col_convert col_x  col_y
type11    type21     col_a       10     100  
type11    type21     col_b       11     101
type11    type21     col_c       12     102
type12    type22     col_a       20     200  
type12    type22     col_b       21     201
type12    type22     col_c       22     202
type13    type23     col_a       30     300  
type13    type23     col_b       31     301
type13    type23     col_c       32     302
```

I tried `melt()`, this method can set `col_level`.

But when I set it to `0`, it will lose level `1`.

When I set it to `1` it will lose level `0`.

I tried `unstack()`, this method can not set something like col_level,

I have to filter the `type1` first and drop column `col_type`,

Then `unstack` the data twice, then append `col_type` as `type1`,

and the `type2`, `type3`...

Is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
{('col_type1', 'col_type1'): {0: 'type11', 1: 'type12', 2: 'type13'},
 ('col_type2', 'col_type2'): {0: 'type21', 1: 'type22', 2: 'type23'},
 ('col_a', 'col_x'): {0: '10', 1: '20', 2: '30'},
 ('col_a', 'col_y'): {0: '100', 1: '200', 2: '300'},
 ('col_b', 'col_x'): {0: '11', 1: '21', 2: '31'},
 ('col_b', 'col_y'): {0: '101', 1: '201', 2: '301'},
 ('col_c', 'col_x'): {0: '12', 1: '22', 2: '32'},
 ('col_c', 'col_y'): {0: '102', 1: '202', 2: '302'}})

df.set_index([('col_type1', 'col_type1'),('col_type2', 'col_type2')])\
  .stack(0)\
  .reset_index()\
  .rename(columns={('col_type1', 'col_type1'):'col_type1',
                   ('col_type2', 'col_type2'):'col_type2',
                   'level_2':'col_convert'})
```

Output:

```
  col_type1 col_type2 col_convert col_x col_y
0    type11    type21       col_a    10   100
1    type11    type21       col_b    11   101
2    type11    type21       col_c    12   102
3    type12    type22       col_a    20   200
4    type12    type22       col_b    21   201
5    type12    type22       col_c    22   202
6    type13    type23       col_a    30   300
7    type13    type23       col_b    31   301
8    type13    type23       col_c    32   302
```

Try, stacking level zero of the multiindex column:

```
df.stack(0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       0 level_1  col_x  col_y
0  type1   col_a     10    100
1  type1   col_b     11    101
2  type1   col_c     12    102
3  type2   col_a     20    200
4  type2   col_b     21    201
5  type2   col_c     22    202
6  type3   col_a     30    300
7  type3   col_b     31    301
8  type3   col_c     32    302
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but in my level_0 is not the `type1, type2, type3`, it's `0 0 0, 1 1 1, 2 2 2`, and I some rows  `col_type type1 NaN NaN, col_type type2 NaN NaN, col_type type3 NaN NaN`

Comment: Are the first two rows of the displayed dataframe in the question in the index?  Can you do df.to_dict() and post that output to your question.  Or better yet put the code to generate your dataframe in the question?

Comment: Thanks, I have put the create data frame code in my question, could you see it again

Comment: @fisheep Using your dataframe and my updated code, it appears to work.